# Can a QGIS project (.qgs) be uploaded to work in map viewer in GIS Cloud?

Tags: qgis, qgis-cloud

Title says it all. Can a QGIS project be uploaded onto GIS CLoud to display all the properties i have asked it to display in QGIS?

if not is there an equvilant GIS Server i can upload previous QGIS project onto so they look like the look on QGIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about GIS Cloud, but there is a similar project specifically for QGIS projects and maps. [QGIS Cloud](http://qgiscloud.com/)

By installing the QGIS Cloud plugin you could upload your maps to the server and share it with other people. [Here is a documentation](http://qgiscloud.com/en/pages/quickstart) how to do that.

Nevertheless consider that .qgs-files are merely XML-like structures, which save the location and loaded properties of your projects. (You can open the .qgs file with a notepad to see how its done) Therefore you've to upload your raster and vector layers too, which could result in pretty big project directories.